# Why I am getting 400 bad request error in aws server for OIDC endpoints

Tags: java, security, filter, java-8, openid-connect

I have implemented OIDC for my project which was initially on UAA shared service model. Now I am authenticating the user via OIDC server by passing the Authorization Bearer Token and x-username object in the header. Everything is running fine in local. But when I deploy my code in aws server, I am getting 400 bad request error for all the endpoints called. On enabling debug on @EnableWebSecurity(debug=true) I am getting this log from the aws server.. But not able to make out what is wrong with the calls.
Any clue will help

```
Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  OIDCRequestFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
************************************************************
2021-09-16 22:18:20 [http-nio-9090-exec-5] DEBUG c.g.d.o.m.c.SecurityRolesFilter.fetchInternalUserRoles - Start Resource ["g00980025", "g00980036", "g01222787", "g01290249", "g01302249", "g01307393", "g01344544", "g01344731", "g01389431", "g01400330", "g01406241"], Groups: 502622018, User: 
{}
.
2021-09-16 22:18:20 [http-nio-9090-exec-8] DEBUG c.g.d.o.m.s.GroupService.findByName - Start G01302249.
2021-09-16 22:18:20 [http-nio-9090-exec-6] DEBUG c.g.d.o.m.s.GroupService.findByName - Start G01222787.
2021-09-16 22:18:20 [http-nio-9090-exec-5] DEBUG c.g.d.o.m.s.GroupService.findGroups - Groups: "g00980025", "g00980036", "g01222787", "g01290249", "g01302249", "g01307393", "g01344544", "g01344731", "g01389431", "g01400330", "g01406241".
2021-09-16 22:18:20 [http-nio-9090-exec-5] DEBUG c.g.d.o.m.s.GroupService.findByName - Start G00980025.
2021-09-16 22:18:20 [http-nio-9090-exec-10] DEBUG c.g.d.o.m.s.GroupService.findByName - Start G01307393.
2021-09-16 22:18:20 [http-nio-9090-exec-9] INFO  Spring Security Debugger.info - 
************************************************************ 
   2021-09-16 22:18:20 [http-nio-9090-exec-5] DEBUG c.g.d.o.m.s.GroupService.findByName - Start G00980025.
    2021-09-16 22:18:20 [http-nio-9090-exec-10] DEBUG c.g.d.o.m.s.GroupService.findByName - Start G01307393.
    2021-09-16 22:18:20 [http-nio-9090-exec-9] INFO  Spring Security Debugger.info - 
    ************************************************************
    New HTTP session created: B3F575F19E09254BE8D861F5FAE62C43
    Call stack: 
        at org.springframework.security.web.debug.Logger.info(Logger.java:46)
        at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter$DebugRequestWrapper.getSession(DebugFilter.java:167)
        at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter$DebugRequestWrapper.getSession(DebugFilter.java:177)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:240)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:240)
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.getSession(ServletRequestAttributes.java:117)
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.obtainSession(ServletRequestAttributes.java:139)
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.getSessionMutex(ServletRequestAttributes.java:264)
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:55)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:371)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:195)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy227.getAccessToken(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.cloud.commons.security.AccessTokenContextRelay.copyToken(AccessTokenContextRelay.java:52)
        at org.springframework.cloud.commons.security.ResourceServerTokenRelayAutoConfiguration$ResourceServerTokenRelayRegistrationAutoConfiguration$1.preHandle(ResourceServerTokenRelayAutoConfiguration.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:148)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1058)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:106)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
        at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:78)
        at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:67)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:398)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:179)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    ************************************************************
```